# Can't import .lhs script in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have two files, `S5.hs` and `S6.lhs`, *in the same folder*, and I want to import the `S6.lhs` script in `S5.hs`, but when i type `import S6`, i get:

```
Could not find module `S6'
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
|
1 | import S6
| ^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

When I lauch it from the folder, I get following message(the first line of the S6 file is *import Data.Array*):

```
    File name does not match module name:
Saw: `Main'
Expected: `S6'
|
1 | import Data.List
| ^
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do you launch ghc from the same directory? Could you show us exactly how you are launching the compilation?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a file named `S6.*` with `module Main where ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you need to specify at the top of the `S6.lhs` file that you want this file to be treated as the `S6` module, as opposed to the default module name of `Main`. You would do that with `module S6 where` or `module S6 (export, list) where`.